# Returning multiple unique values with a vlookup or index match formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

`Column A   Column B    Column C
 Date      Deal Number Item Number
1/28/2018   201809665   1011943002
2/4/2018    201809665   1011943002
2/18/2018   201809665   1011943002
11/5/2017   201745256   1018100005
11/12/2017  201745256   1018100005
11/19/2017  201745256   1018100005
11/26/2017  201745256   1018100005
1/28/2018   201809288   1018100005
2/4/2018    201809288   1018100005
2/11/2018   201809288   1018100005
2/18/2018   201809288   1018100005`

I have a table that looks like the one above, the data is unique based off of the week, deal number, and item number data. I want to figure out how to retrieve all of the date values (from column A) that correspond to a specific item number.

In this example, if I selected Item Number: 1011943002 it would return: 

`1/28/2018
2/4/2018
2/18/2018`

Comment: [this](https://superuser.com/questions/536234/excel-how-to-vlookup-to-return-multiple-values) may be of use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **E2** enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$12, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$999)/($C$2:$C$12=1011943002), ROW(1:1))),"")
```

and copy downwards:

[image]

This assumes that for each item number, the list of dates is unique.